# Is there an app for the Mac that shows you which apps are using the network?

Tags: macos, networking, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application for monitoring all applications that are using the internet in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/50515/application-for-monitoring-all-applications-that-are-using-the-internet-in-mac-o)

I use [Menu Meters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) to show me how much data is being sent and received by my Mac as a whole.

But (as far as I can tell), it doesn’t break it down by application. If there’s a lot of data being sent or received, it’d be nice to see which app is doing it.

Comment: My bounty is for any **free** application which does show **the amount of bandwidth** per application. (I made this as a [separate question](http://superuser.com/questions/205199/macosx-how-much-network-traffic-by-each-app-free-solution-closed) but it was closed as a duplicate to this one and I was told to start a bounty here instead; so here it is).

Comment: @Albert: some Stack Exchange users are a bit heavy on the “no duplication” thing — applying programming principles too literally into real life. Hope you get some useful answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html). It monitors which applications are using the network and also tracks usage. From its website:

> Keep an eye on your traffic
>
> Little Snitch 2 introduces a new
>   Network Monitor, showing detailed
>   information of all incoming and
>   outgoing network traffic.
>
> A status icon in the menu bar provides
>   a summary of current network activity,
>   and a monitor window with more
>   comprehensive information pops up
>   automatically in case of new traffic
>   events.

Comment: Perfect, that’s spot on. You can assign a keyboard shortcut to the network monitor too, if you don’t want it to come up every time something accesses the network.

Answer (score 16):

There is the `lsof` terminal command.  This has a size field (7th field by default).  This has a plethora of switches.  Can probably tell you all you need to know about data connections.

`sudo lsof -i` : this will give you a complete list of all open network connections.  Does not appear to give you the amount of data written or read from each socket though.

When searching for [well-known ports](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers), such as `8080` which is listed as `http-alt` due to its mapping in `/etc/services`, it might be easier to use `lsof -i -P` to suppress conversion of port numbers to  port names. Alternatively, explicitly specify the port one's looking for, like `lsof -i tcp:8080`. When just trying to figure out what services are actually listening, use `lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN`.