# Which process is using a port in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, port, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an app for the Mac that shows you which apps are using the network?](https://superuser.com/questions/47842/is-there-an-app-for-the-mac-that-shows-you-which-apps-are-using-the-network)

I'm trying to start a program in OS X and I get the message:

Port already in use: 8080

I tried LSOF to find out who is using the port but it doesn't have the information. Is there any way I can find out who is using this port so that I can then kill the process?

Comment: (And `lsof -i` *does* show that information.)

Comment: I tried that, using "lsof -i | grep 8080" but it doesn't find the port

Comment: And did you try the other answer on the master question?

Comment: Yes, I saw that, thanks. So should I install "Little Snitch"?

Comment: (I enhanced one of the answers at the duplicate question. Please take any other comments there.)

Comment: And where is that mystical master question?