# How to find the process that is running on a given port in OSX

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, terminal

I want to run a web application on my local OSX Lion machine. When I go to http://localhost:8080 there is already a process running so I get the following message:

```
Status Code: 404

Exception: Request URL / not found.<br><br>
Stacktrace:

Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 at Wed Nov 30 13:01:15 CET 2011
```

How can I find the process that runs on this port under OSX. I found several entries that do the same on Linux but they do not seem to work in OSX.

Thanks a lot.

---

**Update 1**: I running the command `lsof -i -P | grep 8080` results in the following output

```
WebProces 174 petersmith   20u  IPv6 0xffffff80147e6cc0      0t0  TCP localhost:50059->localhost:8080 (ESTABLISHED)
```

But this does not tell me which process is responsible for creating the html output that I get in my browser, when accessing the URL

**Update 2**: I should mention that I want to install [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org) on my machine and there is already an installation present which seems to have a problem on my machine.

Comment: @slhck I did this and updated my answer, but it does not tell me which process is currently running. Curiously `lsof -i tcp:8080` does not result in anything...

Comment: @slhck Seems you're reading my mind. Your link fixed my problem, if you post an Answer I'll happily accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a very general way:

```
sudo lsof -i -P
```

… will list you all processes running on certain ports. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/47855/48078) for more details.

---

In your special case, Jenkins is already running. This Stack Overflow question has more information: [Can not run Jenkins on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309844/can-not-run-jenkins-on-mac). The solution seems to be:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

… which is also related to the similar Stack Overflow question: [How to stop Jenkins installed on Mac Snow Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959327/how-to-stop-jenkins-installed-on-mac-snow-leopard/8008901#8008901)

Comment: curiously `lsof` did not reveal that it was the Jenkins binary that was "occupying" port 8080

Comment: Ah, you know why? Because it's probably a system process and you need to run `sudo lsof`. My bad. Fixed the answer!

Comment: Correct, there we go: `java        54        jenkins  135u  IPv6 0xffffff8014817e80      0t0    TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)`