# How to find and stop a process on a Mac

Tags: macos, unix, process

How can I find the process id and stop the process that is running on port 8080 on a Mac?

On Ubuntu this works:

```
ps -aux
```

and I can find the process and run:

```
kill -9 pid
```

`ps -aux` didn't seem to work, how can I do this on Mac OS X Lion?

Comment: Closely related: [How to find the process that is running on a given port in OSX](http://superuser.com/questions/362966/how-to-find-the-process-that-is-running-on-a-given-port-in-osx/362988#362988), as well as: [Is there an app for the Mac that shows you which apps are using the network?](http://superuser.com/questions/47842/is-there-an-app-for-the-mac-that-shows-you-which-apps-are-using-the-network)

Comment: No. No. No. Please, please, please do not use `kill -9 pid` until after you've tried just `kill pid`. Many processes will have signal handlers which will clean up their use of resources, cleanly close connections and other pre-shutdown tasks. If you kill with -9, the process dies immediately without doing the cleanup. Killing without -9 will work most of the time.

Answer (score 19):

For historical reasons, `ps`'s options are a tangled and inconsistent mess.  On OS X Lion, any of these should work:

```
ps -ax
ps -e
ps aux # this displays in a different format
```

I don't have an ubuntu box handy to test, but according to the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ps.1.html), `ps -aux` isn't the right way to do it there either:

```
Note that "ps -aux" is distinct from "ps aux". The POSIX and UNIX
standards require that "ps -aux" print all processes owned by a user
named "x", as well as printing all processes that would be selected by
the -a option. If the user named "x" does not exist, this ps may
interpret the command as "ps aux" instead and print a warning. This
behavior is intended to aid in transitioning old scripts and habits. It
is fragile, subject to change, and thus should not be relied upon.
```

Answer (score 9):

If you wish to find and kill all processes which conform to a string, you can also use the following on a Mac OSX:

```
ps aux | grep <string> | awk '{print $1}' | <sudo> xargs kill -9
```

Basically what this will do is that it will find (grep) all the processes currently running on your system matching the , AWK gets the PID, which in the PS command is the second column and the last one takes the arguments from AWK and kills the processes.

Use SUDO, only if the current user does not have some rights to kill a process and if you have SUDO access on your system.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Activity Monitor`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_Monitor).

`Applications` -> `Utilities` -> `Activity Monitor`

Answer (score 3):

I believe `ps -ef` on Mac is nearly equivalent to `ps -aux` on linux.

To get what PID has port 8080 in use:    `lsof -P | grep 8080`

The fields map out to:

```
[mini-nevie:~] nevinwilliams% lsof -P | head -1
COMMAND     PID          USER   FD     TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
```

I started up `ttcp -rs` which listens on port 5001.

```
mini-nevie:~] nevinwilliams% lsof -P | grep 5001
ttcp      27999 nevinwilliams    3u    IPv4 0xb70c1f66028d6961       0t0     TCP *:5001 (LISTEN)
```

and indeed, PID 27999 corresponds to the PID of the `ttcp` process I launched.

Comment: You can also use `ps aux` (without the dash) on OS X. `ps -ef` includes different columns and uses a different format.

Comment: I happen not to currently have a linux login to compare; Years ago, IIRC, if -aux didn't give the expected output on a particular flavour of unix, then -ef would...  AIX, Linux, SunOS used -aux, BSD, Solaris needed -ef for compatibility; I forget if IRIX was -aux or -ef.  I don't recall what the major difference in the respective systems were...

Comment: OS X's aux and Ubuntu's aux and -aux use the same format, but Ubuntu's -aux prints a warning at the start.

Comment: Ahha... The split was between SysV and BSD implementations.

Answer (score 1):

To stay up to date, for macOS:

```
ps -e | grep python | awk '{print "sudo kill -9",  $1}' | sh
```

For Linux:

```
ps -ax | grep python | awk '{print "sudo kill -9",  $1}' | sh
```